# error in rumming randomForest with R: "Column `iris.rf` is a `randomForest.formula/randomForest` object."

Tags: r

when I run R's example code for random Forest with data(iris), I got error as below.
Code run:

```
set.seed(71)
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris, importance=TRUE, proximity=TRUE)
print(iris.rf)
```

Error message:
`! All columns in a t I bb le must be vectors.`

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: I tried to update to most recent R and R Studio, the above error gone, but I got new error as below: Error in deprecate_warn("1.1.0", "data_frame()", "tibble()") : 
  could not find function "deprecate_warn"

Comment: Please add the exact code that you used and example data or how to obtain it (in your case, probably just `data(iris)`) so that others can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  That error occurred when I tried to print iris.rf.  The code is: set.seed(71)
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris, importance=TRUE,
                        proximity=TRUE)
print(iris.rf)

Comment: Thanks. I executed your code (after loading the `randomForest` library) and had no error. Have you tried updating the randomForest package?

Comment: Thanks for reminding.  I did but still having error when print(iris.rf). But summary(iris.rf) and plot(iris.rf). Anyway, I can move forward by avoiding print(iris.rf). Thanks very much for your response again!